# Opencart display out of stock at the end on category

Tags: sorting, opencart

How can i sort my products in opencart as like below,

All the products will be sorted by order, but out of stock products(which means if quantity is = 0) will be listed at the end of the category!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In opencart 2.2 you have to change catalog\model\catalog\product.php

find

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
   if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")  ";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
        }
} else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
}
```

and add additional order rule **p.quantity<1** after "ORDER BY"

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
   if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY       p.quantity<1,               LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")  ";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY       p.quantity<1,               (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY       p.quantity<1,                " . $data['sort'];
        }
} else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY           p.quantity<1,                p.sort_order";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 queries. **One** in which `quantity != 0 ORDER BY sort_order` and **second** `quantity = 0`. Then you can merge the records and have your desired output.

Comment: thanks for anwer. I can imagine that too but i need actual codes itself. to understand how it goes :)

Comment: That is a bit long procedure.. It is tricky.. You will have to write make changes in controller, models, and view.. A long procedure.. :(

Comment: Yeah possibly, but i have to figgure it out!